# After reopening app, UIToolbar superview takes up whole view

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, superview

I have a `UIToolbar` setup in a superview on the bottom of my `UITableView` that is part of a `UINavigationController`.

It works fine when I'm using the app; however, when I close (send to background multitask) the app and then reopen it, the `UIToolbar` superview takes up the whole `UITableView` (but not the Navigation Bar). Is there a way to call a `setFrame` when the app reloads? I tried to put an `NSLog` in `viewWillAppear`, but it doesn't get called when I switch back to the app on multitask bar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

```
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

or the

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

methods in the app delegate to implement whatever code you like.